# Check whether the integrand is continuous when evaluating improper integrals

Tags: calculus, continuity, improper-integrals

In order to evaluate improper integrals, I need to know whether the integrand is continuous between the limits of the integral. For the lower and upper limits, I believe you find out if it's continuous at the points if the limit of the integrand as x tends to either the upper or lower limit exists, but how would I find out if the integrand is continuous over the **whole range** and not just at the upper and lower limits?

E.g for this integrand how would I find out if it's continuous over the whole range of the limits given?

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\,\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple ways to show continuity. Could you give us some specific examples?

Comment: Do you need to see how to evaluate the integral?

Answer (score -2):

Some functions are, by definition, continuous, and others are not. For example:

- polynomials are continuous on their domain
- rational functions have a discontinuity when the denominator is equal to $0$
- exponential functions are continuous on their domain
- split functions often have a discontinuity, when the function jumps or has a removable discontinuity
- trigonometric functions such as $\sin$ and $\cos$ are continuous but $
  \csc$, $\sec$, $\tan$ and $\cot$ are not continuous. In the latter case, the functions are still integrable because the integral becomes improper yet can still be evaluated.

In your example, $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ exists, so the function is not discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: "a discontinuity when the denominator" $\: \mapsto \:$ "a point not in their domain when the denominator" $\hspace{.72 in}$

Comment: Are you saying that the point does exist, on another domain?

Comment: No, I'm saying that [continuous at] and [discontinuous at] are just defined for points in the domain. $\hspace{.5 in}$

Comment: Ahorn, I don't agree with your statement that some function are continuous ‘by definition’. You certainly have to prove that polynomials, and others, are continuous; that doesn't immediately follow from the definition of the function. Furthermore, all trigonometric functions, *including* $tan$, $csc$, $sec$ and $cot$, are continuous, because the points where they ‘become infinite’ are not included in the domain; and as Ricky Demer correctly noted: the property of being continuous at a point is only defined for points *inside the domain*.